# FPDF multicell table issue?

Tags: fpdf

I have a problem with auto enter multicell FPDF

```
$pdf=new PDF('P','cm','A4');
$pdf->Open();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetMargins(1.5,1,1.5);
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);

$x=$pdf->GetY();
$pdf->SetY($x+1);
$pdf->SetFont('Times','B',12);
$pdf->Cell(1,0.5,'#',1,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(4,0.5,'Name',1,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(4,0.5,'Blabla',1,0,'L');
$pdf->Cell(4,0.5,'Blabla',1,0,'L');

//query dan arraying
$sql   ="SELECT * FROM `tb_unknown`";
$query = mysql_query( $sql );
$i = 1;

while( $result= mysql_fetch_array( $query )){
   $pdf->Ln();
   $name = $result['name'];
   $blabla1 = $result['blabla1'];
   $blabla2 = $result['blabla2'];
   $pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);
   $pdf->MultiCell(1, 0.5, $i, 1, 'L');
   $pdf->MultiCell(4, 0.5, $name, 1, 'L');
   $pdf->MultiCell(4, 0.5, $blabla1, 1, 'L');
   $pdf->MultiCell(4, 0.5, $blabla2, 1, 'L');
   $i++;
}
$pdf->Output("report.pdf", "I");
```

and this is my result....

[image]

thats so ugly, table false alignment position in.
Somebody can help me to fixed it?...

Comment: Hi! I'm currently facing this issue. I wonder if did you already fixed yours? If yes, then would you mind telling me what did you do? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This one have bothered me for some time and I have found the solution on this [link](http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/fpdf-function-multicell-linewrap-245457.html).

The idea behind this is to take X and Y coordinate before you print multicell, and immediately after you print it set both coordinates using SetXY function.

You also have to determine the height of the highest cell in the row and then move to the appropriate Y coordinate using SetY at the end of each row.

Your code should look like this:

```
$name = $result['name'];
$blabla1 = $result['blabla1'];
$blabla2 = $result['blabla2'];
$pdf->SetFont('Times','',12);

while( $result= mysql_fetch_array( $query )) {  
    $current_y = $pdf->GetY();
    $current_x = $pdf->GetX();
    $pdf->MultiCell(1, 0.5, $i, 1, 'L');
    $end_y = $pdf->GetY();

    $current_x = $current_x + 1;
    $pdf->SetXY($current_x, $current_y);
    $pdf->MultiCell(4, 0.5, $name, 1, 'L');
    $end_y = ($pdf->GetY() > $end_y)?$pdf->GetY() : $end_y;

    $current_x = $current_x + 4;
    $pdf->SetXY($current_x, $current_y); 
    $pdf->MultiCell(4, 0.5, $blabla1, 1, 'L');
    $end_y = ($pdf->GetY() > $end_y)?$pdf->GetY() : $end_y;

    $current_x = $current_x + 4;
    $pdf->SetXY($current_x, $current_y);
    $pdf->MultiCell(4, 0.5, $blabla2, 1, 'L');
    $end_y = ($pdf->GetY() > $end_y)?$pdf->GetY() : $end_y;
    $i++;
    $pdf->SetY($end_y);
}
```